# Histogram and date position in R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, histogram

My histogram doesn't look like it's on the correct date when I plot it.

My data looks like this

```
date        tcol    names
2005-03-31   170    Site 4
2005-03-31   328    Site 5
2005-03-31   40     Site 6
```

My Code looks like

```
ggplot(data=allsite, aes(x=date, weight=tcol, colour=names, fill=names))+
geom_histogram(binwidth=20000, position=position_dodge())+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1000))+
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%d-%m-%y"), 
                 limits = as.POSIXct(c("2005-03-29","2005-04-02")))
```

It's appearing as thought the data is for the 30th of the 3rd and not the 31st
[image: Here's the graph image]

Thanks for any help you can give me :)

Comment: At a quick glance it has to do with you x scale because the limits are also moved back by 1 each. The problem seems to lie in the line `limits = as.POSIXct(c("2005-03-29","2005-04-02"))`

Comment: try scale_x_date() and use as.Date() for limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify the time zone in as.POSIXct

```
limits = as.POSIXct(c("2005-03-29","2005-04-02"), tz="GMT"))
```